# How to retrieve all positions of a profile, including past ones using LinkedIn with the REST API?

Tags: android, api, field, linkedin-api

I am writting an Android app to make use of Linkedin's API.

I want to be able to look all off one person (include current job and all jobs in my past).I am currently using my own implementation of the REST API sided with the People-Search API calls.

This is my Request,that work https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(positions)

The problem is, the response return only the current job (the job that i am working), for the jobs that i didn't work in past not return.

How do i structure my API Call so i can get all the job information include my current jobs and my past jobs ?